# netty 4 LEAK: ByteBuf was GC'd before being released correctly

Tags: java, netty, decoder

I'm getting this warning with my netty server one or two times a day while decode methods treats more than 800 packets/day.

The line that it does not seem to like is the `super.decode()` line but I'm not sure whether it's because of the `buffer` variable (the local one) or the `buf` variable (the `bytebuf` that I receive).

I added the `release()` in the `finally` block but the warning is still there.

I'm using the netty 4.0.4 final.

```
WARN  ResourceLeakDetector - LEAK: ByteBuf was GC'd before being released correctly.  The following stack trace shows where the leaked object was created, rather than where you failed to release it.
io.netty.util.ResourceLeakException: io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf@13e5013
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector$DefaultResourceLeak.<init>(ResourceLeakDetector.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector.open(ResourceLeakDetector.java:116)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.<init>(UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:72)
    at io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(UnpooledByteBufAllocator.java:49)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:123)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:60)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.extractFrame(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:486)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:425)
    at PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:62)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.decode(LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.java:351)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:231)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:780)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:465)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:359)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code:

```
@Override
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info(" in the decode handler ");
    ByteBuf buffer = ((ByteBuf) super.decode(ctx, buf)).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    if (buffer == null) {
        LOGGER.error(" not all the message is received or a null message ");
        return null;
    }
    try {

        // reading the buffer until the end 
        // return something other than null     
        }

    }
    catch ( Exception e ){
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
     finally {
         buffer.retain();
         buffer.release();
        }

}
```

Comment: Why do you call ` buffer.retain();` in the finally block?

Comment: Because The readindex reaches 0 at The End of my try block so i thought that i can t call release directly correct me if i m wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be confused what the meaning of `buffer.retain();`, this increases the internal reference count of the object, you only use it under special circumstances. You probably meant to only call `buffer.release()` in the finally block

Comment: thank you, it was not clear for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you not always call ByteBuf.release(). You should ensure you always release buffers.

Comment: You mean to call ByteBuf.release() in the catch block too? thank you